# Change text after a while on Activity start

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I have a text written in my app. I want it to be changed after some time automatically after the app starts. I need to invoke a method somewhere so that it can be called automatically.
I've tried putting my code in `onStart()` method, but that delays the starting of my app,
that's why I want my method to be invoked after `onStart()` method.

In other words, I want my app to get started, see the previous text and after waiting for some fixed time (I will use `Thread.sleep(ms)`) it would change to some other text.

I need to submit a project. Please help me with the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Check Android documentation on Activities: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of app responsiveness, as stated in the official documentation on [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads), it is not recommended to block the `UI-thread` (for example by calling `Thread.sleep()`) longer than a few seconds. As also described in the article provided there are several options to avoid that, one of which is to use `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, int)` method with the timeout indicating when the new text should show up:

```
private static final int TIME_OUT = 1000; // [ms]
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
    tv.setText("This is the text to appear when Activity starts up");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            tv.setText("New text to be shown after TIME_OUT");

        }
    }, TIME_OUT);
}
```